# okta jwt verifier for php 5 is throwing an error with requires php7

Tags: php, jwt, okta

I am new to okta and we are implementing okta integration in our application we will receive the okta access token in the header and we need to validate that.

for that i am trying to use okta/jwt-verifier and i am getting an error okta/jwt-verifier 0.1.0 requires php ^7.0.

Does anyone has any idea which dependency to be used for php5 to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: How is the error message not the answer?

Answer (score 4):

All of the tools from Okta for PHP require you to have PHP7+.  The verifier you are trying to use will not install under the PHP5 environment.  You will need to upgrade your PHP environment to at least PHP7 for it to work.

The reason behind this decision is that PHP5.x is now deprecated and no longer supported, so we want to make sure that our users have the most up to date PHP version.  You can find information on these version at http://php.net/supported-versions.php

At Okta, we suggest that you have the latest version of PHP at all time, and at this time, that would be PHP 7.2